# Android sqlite sort listview using radiobutton

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, cursor

I make a listview that the data are take from sqlite 
now i want to make it will sort by name or location using radiobutton

this is my code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        RadioButton rbname = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                RadioButton rblocation = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);

            if (rbname.isChecked()){
            Cursor = db
                .getReadableDatabase()
                .rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM " + DatabaseHelper.LIST + " ORDER BY " + DatabaseHelper.NAME, null);  
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, Cursor,
                new String[] {DatabaseHelper.NAME, DatabaseHelper.ADDRESS, DatabaseHelper.GENDER, DatabaseHelper.LOCATION},
                new int[] {R.id.txtName, R.id.txtAddress, R.id.txtGender, R.id.txtLocation});       
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            }

            else if (rblocation.isChecked()){
                Cursor = db
                        .getReadableDatabase()
                        .rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM " + DatabaseHelper.LIST+ " ORDER BY " + DatabaseHelper.LOCATION, null);   
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, Cursor,
                        new String[] {DatabaseHelper.NAME, DatabaseHelper.ADDRESS, DatabaseHelper.GENDER, DatabaseHelper.LOCATION},
                        new int[] {R.id.txtName, R.id.txtAddress, R.id.txtGender, R.id.txtLocation});       
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
            }


        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }
```

I already try to put `Cursor.requery()` already try to change ListAdapter to BaseAdapter
so I can use `notifydatasetchanged()`

but nothing happen.. my listview still not update

please help me how to solve this problem

Comment: so after the radiobutton is **re**-checked, you want it to change the listview correct? not just the once.

Comment: @mango ya.. everytime i check the radiobutton it will change.. it will sort the listview.. I try many ways but nothing work.. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is put your code into into *listeners* so that your event activates after the button has been clicked and not the once in `onCreate`. In addition getting a listview backed by a cursor to change is done be re-instantiating a cursor and calling `changeCursor` on the adapter. I hope the following code makes things clearer:

```
private RadioButton rbname, rblocation;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    rbname = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rblocation = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);

    Cursor cursor = db
            .getReadableDatabase()
            .rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM " + DatabaseHelper.LIST + " ORDER BY " + DatabaseHelper.NAME, null);
    // a default cursor
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, Cursor,
            new String[] {DatabaseHelper.NAME, DatabaseHelper.ADDRESS, DatabaseHelper.GENDER, DatabaseHelper.LOCATION},
            new int[] {R.id.txtName, R.id.txtAddress, R.id.txtGender, R.id.txtLocation});       
    setListAdapter(adapter);    // do the adapter stuff here to avoid repeating code
    initListeners(); // set up the listeners for the radio buttons

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

private void initListeners() {

    rbname.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                Cursor cursor = db
                        .getReadableDatabase()
                        .rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM " + DatabaseHelper.LIST + " ORDER BY " + DatabaseHelper.NAME, null);
                adapter.changeCursor(cursor); // change cursor in adapter so that listview changes                  
            }               
        }
    });

    rblocation.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                Cursor cursor = db
                        .getReadableDatabase()
                        .rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM " + DatabaseHelper.LIST+ " ORDER BY " + DatabaseHelper.LOCATION, null);   
                adapter.changeCursor(cursor);   
            }               
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem long time ago, what helped was to generate a refresh-method. So every time i needed a refresh, I simply called this method.

```
         private void refresh() {
           ListView yourListView = getListView();   
           list = getList(); //this is a List<string>
           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,R.layout.your_listview_item,list); //this is ArrayAdapter<String>       
           yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
           yourListView.invalidateViews();
}
```

This worked good in my ListActivity

Comment: thx.. but what is that list = getList(); its error and it using ArrayAdapter ? is it ok ? cause I use a simplecursoradapter for my listview..

Comment: In my app I save Strings, it is a List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>. My getList() method is to read datas from the database-table and returning this as an ArrayList<String>. In my case an arrayAdapter works fine, but this could be very different on other needs. The thing I wanted to show You is, after You have done Your sortings, use a refresh like in this example (but not exactly the same way). In Your case, I think after getting sortet datas and setting listAdapter, you have to refresh your ListView with invalidateViews(), if this is possible.